# Nexus 7 cannot acts as Handsfree

Tags: bluetooth, nexus-7, nexus-4, a2dp

Today I watched this video in below url and I am wondering why Google Nexus 7 and Google Nexus 4 cannot act like this. Unable see the incoming call coming from paired device in Nexus.

URL:  http://support-us.samsung.com/spstv/detail.jsp?ctg_id=209&sub_ctg_id=&live_id=8

I have updated both the device to Android 4.3.

Have I missed any settings or Nexus does not support A2DP? or only Galaxy Player supports this?

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth has a master/slave setup, in which the other device is a master (for example, a phone) and the other a slave (a headset). Most phones support the hands-free profile only as a master, which means that the phone can connect to slave devices and stream its audio to the device, not the other way around. Apparently Samsung has included support for HFP slave on it's Player models, which is reasonable since they don't have phone functionality builtin.

Therefore, it's not a question of settings, it's a question of support.